# Cannor resolve symbol 'rx'

Tags: android, android-studio, rx-java2

I used 1.3.4 version and everything was fine but I started using 2.1.9 version and I have mistake"Cannor resolve symbol 'rx'"
This is my Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.max.project_oo1_client_server"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.9'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
```

}

Comment: your import statement should change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in your import statements.

Search : `import rx.Observable;`

Replace: `import io.reactivex.Observable;`

repeat this for all classes.

you can use search and replace but be carefull :

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on Windows and Linux/Ubuntu

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on Mac OS X